# Running a dictionary with a while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to insert a while loop into this program so when it asks for member it starts a dictionary (assuming I would use a dictionary) that lets me input n number of band members and the instrument they use in some form like (name,instrument),(name2,instrument2)..and so on. I know it will be run as a while loop, but I'm not not sure how to enter it in this instance. Would using a dictionary be the best action and if so how would I add it in a case like this?

```
 class Song:


        def __init__(self, song, chart, member):
            self.song = song
            self.chart = chart
            self.member = member

        def __str__(self):
            return (self.song
                    + " Top Chart:"
                    + str(self.chart)
                    + " Band Members: "
                    + str(self.member)
                    + '\n')

    def write():

        with open("string.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as f:


            while(1):


                prompt = ":\t"
                in_song = input("Input song or type q " + prompt)
                if (in_song == 'q'):
                    break

                in_chart_spot = input("Input chart spot" + prompt)

                in_band_mem = input("Input band members" + prompt)


                song_data = Song(in_song, in_chart_spot, in_band_mem)
                #albumdata = Album()


                f.write(str(song_data))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        write()
```

Comment: pro tip: python doesn't require parentheses for control-flow statements. So just `while True:` or `if in_song == 'q':` work fine.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you are asking. You seem to be writing to a file. Are you asking how to insert items in a `dict`?

Comment: I am trying to make it so I can add multiple members instead of just one when it writes to the txt file. At the same time im trying to attach an inputted instrument to each inputted  member.

Comment: An example of the string being saved would be:                       SONGNAME Top Chart:NUMBER Band Members: ((BANDMEMBER1,INSTRUMENT1),(BANDMEMBERn,INSTRUMENTn).....)